# Alternate presentation of the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra over the unit interval

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

Just after a few month of not touching the subject, I'm already rusty on the key ideas:
My off the top definition for the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra over the unit interval is 
$$ \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]} = \sigma([a,b[ \: | \: a<b \in [0,1])$$.

Can somebody share a presentation along the lines of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\cap \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}$?

I started with  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\cap [0,1] = \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}$ which made no sense, considered both $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\cap \sigma([0,1])$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\cap \mathfrak{P}([0,1])$, which are both wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal B([0,1]) = \{A \cap [0,1]: A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}
= \{B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R): B \subseteq [0,1]\}$.
If $\mathfrak P([0,1])$ means the power set of $[0,1]$, that is
$\mathcal B(\mathbb R) \cap \mathfrak P([0,1])$.

Comment: I meant indeed the power set of $[0,1]$ with $\mathfrak{P}([0,1])$. Thank you for your answer! I have a follow up question though: so the last part, did I understand you correctly that $$\mathcal{B}(R) \cap \mathfrak{P}([0,1]) = \mathcal{B}([0,1])$$ If yes: How would one show "$\subset$"

Comment: Let $\mathcal A$ be the set of all subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that $A \cap [0,1] \in \mathcal B([0,1])$.  This is a $\sigma$-algebra and contains all open sets, so it contains $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.  If $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $A \in \mathfrak P([0,1])$, then $A \in \mathcal A$ and $A = A \cap [0,1]$, so $A \in \mathcal B([0,1])$.